# Is it better to pass by value or by reference for basic datatypes?

Tags: c++, performance, reference

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to pass objects to functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139224/how-to-pass-objects-to-functions-in-c)
>   [is there any specific case where pass-by-value is preferred over pass-by-const-reference in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898789/is-there-any-specific-case-where-pass-by-value-is-preferred-over-pass-by-const-re)

I have members of a class implemented like this:

```
void aaa(int a, float b, short c)
{
  bbb(a, b);
}

void bbb(int a, float b)
{}
```

If the values of a, b and c were stored in my class as constants, then would it have been better/sensible to use my functions as shown below or as shown above?

```
void aaa(int& a, float& b, short& c)
void bbb(int& a, float& b)
```

Does using references give any speed benefits or advantages in this case? Any disadvantages/overheads of references here?

Comment: Ok, what are all those `*` about?!

Comment: i suppose you need to edit the format int**&** makes no sense :-)

Comment: The asterixes was added by StackOverflow. The website was supposed to connvert the letters between asterisks to Bold. Will remove it coz it's not converting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Standard doesn't have constraints about implementation of references, however usually they're implemented as autodereferenced pointers (actually with some exceptions). As you probably know, on 32 bit system pointer size is 4 bytes, that means that passing chars, shorts (types with sizeof() less than 4 bytes) by reference maybe considered as somewhat overkilling - using 4 bytes instead of 1 (char) or 2 (short). 
In general it depends on whether the rigisters or stack is used for passing parameters: you can save a bit of stack when passing basic types by value, but in case of registers even for chars, 4 bytes will be used, so there's no point in trying to optimize something with ptrs/refs.

Comment: Note that there is another difference in performance: when using an int directly, the value is present in either the register or the stack, while when passing references (assuming an auto-dereferenced pointer) the actual value has to be retrieved with an extra indirection, that would be unnecessary if passing by value.

Comment: -1 For propagating misconception about stack usage. Passing a `char`, say, on the stack, will typically use 4 bytes of stack space on a 32-bit system. In C and C++ the same underlying reason is reflected in automatic promotion to `int`. In short, stack space usage has nothing to do with it for the small types. Instead it has to do with programmer time, how much you need to write and how much you need to read, i.e. programmer efficiency, and it has to do with a possible extra indirection, i.e. program efficiency.

Comment: Uh, who voted up again this incorrect answer?

Answer (score 6):

In the case of ordinal types — i.e. int, float, bool, etc. — there is no savings in using a reference instead of simply using pass by value. [Source](http://developer.kde.org/~wheeler/cpp-pitfalls.html) [Source2](http://www.eventhelix.com/RealtimeMantra/Basics/OptimizingCAndCPPCode.htm)

Answer (score 5):

If you use references, make them `const`:

```
void bbb(const int & a, const float & b);
```

Otherwise the semantics will be different from passing by value, as the function could change the value of the variables passed to the parameters. This would imply that you could not use literals for the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the reason why it would be faster. You need to send the parameter to the function in both case. If the function get pointer instead of value, then the pointer needs dereferencing which might be slower than sending plain value.

Comment: In case of a pointer `*`, there will be dereferencing, in case of a *reference* `&`, there will be no "overhead" involved. For types larger than the native register used for function arguments (normally the size of a memory address), it is in theory better to pass references instead of whole objects by value.

Comment: @rubenvb: The fact that you do not need to explicitly dereference does not mean that there is no implicit dereference. In many (all?) compilers, references are implemented as automatically dereferenced pointers. Using a reference implies an implicit indirection in the generated assembler (unless the function is inlined --where the compiler can use the actual variables)

Comment: I think we are talking about something like `int` or `float`. However, the * and & is pretty much just different syntax for pointer-type parameter, so I guess David is right here.

Comment: Ah, I thought a reference would take the internal form of an aliased variable, and avoid the whole pointer dereferencing mechanism. Guess I was wrong...