# I am coding Node struct and I think this is constructor initializer error

Tags: c++, class, data-structures, constructor, linked-list

I am coding struct `Node` and I think this is constructor initializer error. What did I write wrong?

```
class linkedlist 
{
private:
    struct Node
    {
        char m_num;
        char m_logo;
        char m_name;
        char m_1;
        int m_2;
        Node* next;
    };
    Node() 
        : m_num(), m_logo(), m_name(), m_1(), m_2(), next(nullptr) // error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token|
    {}
    Node(const char& a, const char& b, const char& c, const char& d, const int& e) 
        : m_num(a), m_logo(b), m_name(c), m_1(d), m_2(e), next(nullptr) // error: expected unqualified-id before 'const'|
    {}                                                                  // error: expected ')' before 'const'| 

    Node* head = nullptr;
    Node* tail = nullptr;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move your `Node` constructors inside the definition of `Node` class.

```
struct Node
{
    char m_num;
    char m_logo;
    char m_name;
    char m_1;
    int m_2;
    Node* next;
    Node() 
        : m_num(), m_logo(), m_name(), m_1(), m_2(), next(nullptr)
    {}
    Node(const char& a, const char& b, const char& c, const char& d, const int& e) 
        : m_num(a), m_logo(b), m_name(c), m_1(d), m_2(e), next(nullptr)
    {}
};
```

or you need to declare the constructors inside the `Node` class defenition beforehand.

Comment: Thank you. Can you show me what is the other way? (declare what? )

Comment: @JackyTeerapat It needs the `Node` as public. I wouldn't go for that as `Node` is a `private` property of `linkedlist`. However here is it: https://wandbox.org/permlink/MuzBDbQ3WBmCFLGd

Comment: @JackyTeerapat Also note that **the primitive types can be passed by value than ref**:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013139/is-it-counter-productive-to-pass-primitive-types-by-reference. That means. `Node` 's second constructor  could be simply: `Node(char a, char b, char c, char d, int e)`

Comment: Do you mean to change anything to the public? @JeJo

Comment: **"the primitive types can be passed by value than"** It means I can't pass by ref? Does it work the only method?

Comment: @JackyTeerapat Yes. Looks like `Node` has to be an internal type of class `linkedlist`, and hence, my the second option is not a good idea.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196736/discussion-between-jejo-and-jacky-teerapat).