# Stable sort custom comparator using pass by reference with lamdas gives compile error

Tags: c++, sorting, lambda, stl, stable-sort

https://leetcode.com/problems/move-zeroes/ was solving this question.
But this doesnot compile.

```
void moveZeroes(vector<int>& nums) {
    

    stable_sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(),[](int& a, int& b){
            if(a == 0 && b != 0){
                return false;
            }
            if(a != 0 && b == 0){
                return true;
            }
            else {return false;}
        });
    }
```

However if we use pass by value that is
`(int a, int b)` it compiles.
What is the underlying issue??

Comment: What error message is your compiler giving you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lambda can take its arguments as refs. The problem is that in your example, they are not const-ref, and [`std::stable_sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort#Parameters) passes const values,

> **comp**
>
> - [...] The signature of the
>   comparison function should be equivalent to the following:
>
>   ```
>   bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
>   ```
>
>   While the signature does not need to have `const &`, **the function    must not modify the objects passed to it and must be able
>   to accept    all values of type (possibly `const`) `Type1` and `Type2`
>   regardless of    value category (thus, `Type1 &` is not allowed**, nor
>   is `Type1` unless    for `Type1` a move is equivalent to a copy (since
>   C++11)).

which cannot be converted to non-const ref. Simply declare the lambda to take `const int&` instead:

```
stable_sort(nums.begin(), nums.end(),[](const int& a, const int& b) {
    // ...
  });
```

The compiler error is a dead giveaway (filename truncated for brevity):

```
bits/predefined_ops.h:177:11: error: no match for call to ‘(moveZeroes(std::vector<int>&)::<lambda(int&, int&)>) (int&, const int&)’
  177 |  { return bool(_M_comp(*__it, __val)); }
      |           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
bits/predefined_ops.h:177:11: note: candidate: ‘bool (*)(int&, int&)’ <conversion>
bits/predefined_ops.h:177:11: note:   conversion of argument 3 would be ill-formed:
bits/predefined_ops.h:177:11: error: binding reference of type ‘int&’ to ‘const int’ discards qualifiers
```

Comment: or [since it is a primitive type, also `[](const int a, const int b)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013139/is-it-counter-productive-to-pass-primitive-types-by-reference), no ref required.