# Perfect forwarding variadic template with pass by value for selected types

Tags: c++, templates, perfect-forwarding

It is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898789/is-there-any-specific-case-where-pass-by-value-is-preferred-over-pass-by-const-re) and [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270408/is-it-better-in-c-to-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-constant-reference) that it's sometimes preferable to pass by value instead of passing by reference.

In light of that, is it possible to select some types to be passed by value in conjunction with perfect forwarding variadic templates?

```
template<typename... Args>
void foo(Args&&...);  // passes everything by reference

template<typename... Args>
void foo(Args...);  // passes everything by value

template<typename... Args>
void foo(std::conditional_t<is_selected_v<Args>, Args, Args&&>...); // won't deduce types

template<typename... Args>
void foo(...);  // this is wrong :)
```

Note not being able to deduce types means it won't work for constructors

Comment: uhm, I'd argue that perfect forwarding functions are almost always used when inlining is possible/probable, making the need of pass by value far less obvious ...

Comment: Do you want to pass all the arguments by value if some condition is met, or do you want to pass some by value and some by reference? The latter does not seem possible...

Comment: @Knoep The latter. I can't think of anything that can do that, hence the question

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes I don't remotely know how optimizers work, but I'd guess a large function won't get inlined all that often. Or heavily recursive functions

Comment: if the function is "large" then the reasons mentioned in the links justifying passing by value do not apply. Note that if perfect forwarding functions were not inlined ( and optimized ) when reasonable, most template magic based on it would be pretty useless in practice ...

Comment: @MassimilianoJanes Why does the reasons not apply? Anyways, there are some recursive functions that won't be inlined properly, like [this contrived example](https://godbolt.org/g/bTRGur)

Comment: "like this contrived example" this is more a ( bad ) implementation issue, rather than a parameter passing problem ( nothing would forbid the author of that function to detect small types and forward by value to an internal optimized function accordingly ... )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the best we could do is

```
template<typename T>
using pass_policy_t = std::conditional_t<
  std::is_scalar<std::decay_t<T>>::value,
    std::decay_t<T>,
    T&&>;

template<typename... Args>
void foo_impl( pass_policy_t<Args>... );

template<typename... Args>
inline void foo( Args&&... args )
{
  foo_impl<Args...>( std::forward<Args>(args)... );
}
```

where pass_policy_t computes the actual pass type ( in the example above, scalar types decay ). Of course, there's no guarantee foo will be opimized, anyway I'd be happy to see a reasonable situation where it does not ... :) here is a [live snippet](https://godbolt.org/g/RWzcJt) for trying ...

for completeness sake, there was a standard proposal about the issue ( [n3445](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3445.html) ) but it seems gone nowhere ... anyway, 1) it supports the suspect that it's not currently possible without more language support and 2) it shows that even having a pass-by-value policy in full programmer control, it would not be optimal anyway without something like a *is_fast_pass* intrinsic trait ...

Comment: This is a great idea! Did you do some tests that it's actually works in most circumstances?

Comment: @Knoep I've added a concrete pass policy for testing; basic tests do inline as far as I can tell ...

Comment: Yup, tried it with `is_empty` and custom copy constructors. Things are copied when they should be.