# How to conditionally get a `T` or `const T&` from template type `T`?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, function-templates, conditional-types

I want to have my template function `print`(The actual cenario is more complex template function) to have either a `const T&` or just `T`(pass by value), depending up on the characteristics of type `T`.

In other words, if a type `T` is easily copyable **(i.e. such as primitive types `int`, `float`, `double`, `std::initializer_list<>`, trivially copyable, etc...)** and does not make a lot of copying effort, I want to have template instatiation **pass by value**, otherwise a **const l-value reference** to the passed type `T`.

After researching I figured out the folloing two way of doing it.
I tried with both `std::conditional_t` as well as `if constexpr` function `decltype`ing as follows:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std::string_literals;

#if 1 // template function way --- (1)

template<typename T>
constexpr auto type_helper() noexcept
{
    if constexpr (std::is_fundamental_v<T>) return T{};
    else return std::add_const_t<std::add_lvalue_reference_t<T>>{};
};

template<typename T> using conditional_copy_ref_t = decltype(type_helper<T>());

#elif 0 // using std::conditional_t  --- (2)
template<typename T>
using conditional_copy_ref_t = std::conditional_t<std::is_fundamental_v<T>, T, const T&>;

#endif


template <typename T>
auto print(conditional_copy_ref_t<T> arg) noexcept 
// could not deduce template ^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument for 'T'
{
    // do something with arg!
    
};

int main()
{
    print(5);        // should be pass by value
    print("string"s);// should be const std::string&
}
```

Here is the code in online compilers:  https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/5fEaE3M5o

However, both the implementations fails due to the fact of **non-deduced context template deduction**(I have researched agin to understand the error)!

In MSVS I have the error:

```
error C2672: 'print': no matching overloaded function found
error C2783: 'auto print(unknown-type) noexcept': could not deduce template argument for 'T'
```

**What am I doing wrong? Is it even possible? How to fix this error and get the correct type here?**

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46723462/perfect-forwarding-variadic-template-with-pass-by-value-for-selected-types

Answer (score 1):

Because `T` is in a [non-deduced context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245453/what-is-a-nondeduced-context), there is no way for the compiler to deduce the type of `T`. Instead, you can use `enable_if` to help the compiler deduce the type of `T`

```
template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_fundamental_v<T>>
print(T) noexcept { /* */ }


template <typename T>
std::enable_if_t<!std::is_fundamental_v<T>>
print(const T&) noexcept { /* */ }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9s6EPvGhb)

Comment: This goes back to C++11era. Op is asking something in C++17, which will not divide the function in to two parts.

Comment: If you think there's a better way, we'd be interested to see it @LernerCpp.

Comment: @davidgrayson better is giving a more indirection like the post mentioned user Passer By

Comment: I do not think so. In his answer, `foo` is *pass by reference*, then forwards parameters either pass by reference or pass by value via `foo_impl`. So what's the point if you're already *passed by reference* in the first place?

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I found a way to go from Passer By's post. I had actually a varibale template args which could contain a expensively copayable type. Here is my final solution: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/shPMdf7nj

Comment: But isn't your`print_args` pass by reference? In that case, why not just pass *all* parameters by reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the compiler what `T` is explicitly so it doesn't have to deduce it:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
using conditional_copy_ref_t = std::conditional_t<std::is_fundamental_v<T>, T, const T&>;

template <typename T>
auto print(conditional_copy_ref_t<T> arg) noexcept 
{
};

int main()
{
    print<int>(5);
    print<std::string>("string");
}
```

[Test this code on Godbolt](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/avo6orsKj)

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I found a way to go from Passer By's post. I had actually a varibale template args which could contain a expensively copayable type. Here is my final solution: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/shPMdf7nj