# why pass by reference better?

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it better in C++ to pass by value or pass by constant reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270408/is-it-better-in-c-to-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-constant-reference)

see these 2 program.

```
bool isShorter(const string s1, const string s2);

int main()
{
    string s1 = "abc";
    string s2 = "abcd";
    cout << isShorter(s1,s2); 
}

bool isShorter(const string s1, const string s2)
{
    return s1.size() < s2.size();
}
```

and

```
bool isShorter(const string &s1, const string &s2);

int main()
{
    string s1 = "abc";
    string s2 = "abcd";
    cout << isShorter(s1,s2); 
}

bool isShorter(const string &s1, const string &s2)
{
    return s1.size() < s2.size();
}
```

Why second one is better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read this [SO Question - Is it better in C++ to pass by value or pass by constant reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270408/is-it-better-in-c-to-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-constant-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Because it doesn't have to copy the strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you're really interested in some cases when passing by value may be better, you might want to see [**this.**](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/)