# c++ .h and .cpp files - about methods

Tags: c++

HI.

How can I define a bool method in .h file and work with it in the cpp file?
I have

my.h

```
#include <string>

public class me;
class me
{
public:
me();

private bool method(string name); //it is ok??

}
```

my.cpp

```
#include 'my.h';
me::me()
{
method(string name); //can i do this? isn't there another alternative?
}

method (String name)
{
cout<<"name"<<endl;
}
```

is not working.why?

Comment: @dreamlax: philosophy is on another forum :) if you can't help, don't; if the question is really bad, downvote

Comment: I fixed the formatting for you and removed the Linux and Ubuntu references. They're not relevant. You need to specify what you mean by "is not working".

Comment: A small note about terminology: What's known as a "method" in C# and Java is called a "member function" in C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of issues with your code.

my.h

```
#include <string>

// public class me; // Absolutely not needed. From which language did you get this?

class me
{
public:
me();

private: // You need the colon here. 

bool method(string name); //it is ok?? // No. The class is called std::string. You should pass it by const-reference (const std::string& name);

}
```

my.cpp

```
#include 'my.h';
me::me()
{
// `name` is undefined here. You also don't need to specify the type.
//method(string name); //can i do this? isn't there another alternative? 
    method("earl");
}

// method (String name) // See previous comment about const-reference and the name of the class. Also note that C++ is case-sensitive. You also need to specify the return type and the class name:
bool me::method(const std::string& name)
{
    // cout<<"name"<<endl; // Close...
    std::cout << "My name is " << name << std::endl;
    return true; // we are returning a `bool, right?
}
```

You'll also need to call your code:

```
int main()
{
    me instance_of_me;
    return 0;
}
```

I suggest you take a look for [a good C++ tutorial](http://www.4p8.com/eric.brasseur/cppcen.html) and [some reading material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books).

### Answers to questions in the comments:

> could you please tell me why do I need to pass std::string through reference?

This question has already been asked (more than once) on StackOverflow. I recommend [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270408/is-it-better-in-c-to-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-constant-reference/270435#270435).

> And what is with me mo?

In hindsight `mo` was a terrible choice for a variable name. `instance_of_me` may have been a better choice. This line constructs an instance of `me`, calling the constructor (which in turn calls `method("earl")`)

> You meant me method("hello"); in the main()

I certainly did not!

You declared `method` as a `private` member function. This method cannot, therefore, be called from outside the class.

Comment: Johnsyweb could you please tell me why do I need to pass std::string through reference? And what is with me mo? You meant me method("hello"); in the main()

Comment: @linuxx: I have updated my answer to address these comments. Hope that helps. Were you to compile it, you would see an error on calling `method("hello")`!

Answer (score 8):

I suggest you learn the basics of C++ from a tutorial

my.h

```
#include <string>

class me
{
    public:
       me();

       bool method(std::string name) const;
};
```

my.cpp

```
#include 'my.h';

me::me()
{
}

bool me::method(std::string name)
{
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
}
```

As written, there is no need for me::method to be a member function (it could be a static).

Numerous little fixes there. I get the sense that you are coming from C# (possibly java). Read up on the differences. Google has good sources :)

Comment: The usual comment: 
Get a good [book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) (I recommend 2 and 4 from the beginners list to you), to learn C++ correctly. 
As you seem to already know some other (similar) language: Pay special attention to the differences in style and ideom used, do NOT try to write code as if you were still programming in that other language.

Comment: when do i have to pass a string though reference? what does that mean? could you explain a little?

Comment: @linuxx: don't worry about that for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have missed `:` after `private`

Second, if `method (String name)` in the cpp file should be the `method (String name)` from your class, it must be:

```
bool me::method(std::string name)
{
    // ...
}
```

Third, if you want this `bool me::method(std::string name)` to be different function, a global one, not from you class, it must be:

```
ret_type method(std::string name)
{
    // ...
}
```

And, fourth,

```
cout<<"name"<<endl;
```

will pring the string (literal) "name". If you want to print the variable `name`, use it without the quotes:

```
std::cout<< name <<endl;
```

I'd recommend you to get a [book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194812/list-of-freely-available-programming-books)

---

Ah, and this one:

```
me::me()
{
    method(string name); //can i do this? isn't there another alternative?
}
```

`method(string name)` - this is not valid syntax. It should be something like:

```
me::me()
{
    string name;
    // do something with name
    method( name ); // if "method" is a method, for real
}
```