# Moving arguments or passing them the usual C++98/03 way?

Tags: c++, c++11, argument-passing, move-semantics

Suppose that there is a `Person` class like this:

```
// "string" is std::string, "move" is std::move

class Person
{
public:
    // C++11 way: pass by value and std::move() from the value
    Person(string name, string surname)
        : m_name(move(name)), m_surname(move(surname))
    {}

    ....

private:
    string m_name;
    string m_surname;
};
```

Suppose that I read the `name` and `surname` values from some source (e.g. a file) in some loop, and in each loop iteration I want to create a `Person` with these read values (and e.g. push the created `Person` in some container).

Is it better to call `Person` constructor in the usual way:

```
Person(name, surname)
```

or using `std::move` for the arguments?

```
Person(move(name), move(surname))
```

Comment: The second way if you no longer need `name` or `surname`.

Comment: @Simple: Yes, I no longer need them, since at each loop iteration new values are read from some source.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd recommend against making this complicated by choosing to use `Person(move(name), move(surname))` without a particular reason for doing so.

Consider a simple loop reading names and constructing Person objects:

```
string name, surname;
while ((cin >> name) && (cin >> surnam)) {
  Person p(name, surname);
  // ...
}
```

This does result in copies of `name` and `surname` for each `Person`, but the allocation behavior in this context actually turns out to be efficient. Since `name` and `surname` retain their own buffers, those buffers just get reused for the next input operation, which means that once those buffers are large enough no additional allocations occur just for the input. So on average you should get just the one allocation per `name` and `surname` that occurs during the copy.

If you use `move()` to save the one allocation during the copy, then allocation is done during the input operation instead and you can possibly get multiple allocations as the buffer grows dynamically while reading. That means you could potentially do many more allocations when using `move()`.

Furthermore, the copy allocates the minimal amount of memory needed, whereas the strings used in the input operation may have 'extra' based on whatever dynamic growth strategy `string` employs. Therefore explicit moves could result in greater memory usage by persisting that 'extra' into the `Person` objects.

---

So by default just do what's simple and straightforward. I think using `move()` by default here is a case of premature optimization.

Answer (score 5):

The second way if you no longer need `name` or `surname`. If you still need one of them however then you should use the first (or `move` one but not the other).

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Either way, the only constructor is called and a copy of the arguments is done. What you really 'need' is a second constructor accepting rvalue references (in fact it takes 3  additional constructors to be optimal in this case for all the combination of rvalue/lvalue). Then you'd be able to move/forward the arguments to the constructor and get reel benefits.</strike>

Nevermind, this is wrong. C++11 way = pass-by-value-then-move when you know you'll need a copy at some point. This saves time and energy as you don't have to write rvalue overloads.

As already mentioned, you should not move variables you want to access later.

Edit:
See this related question : [C++11 Const reference VS move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642357/c11-const-reference-vs-move-semantics)

Answer (score 0):

You've declared your constructor to take copies rather than reference, so you're creating a new object whenever you call the constructor. You'd be better off passing by reference:

```
Person(const string &name, const string &surname)
        : m_name(name), m_surname(surname)
```

You're still doing the same number of object constructions as before, but now you're no longer using `std::move`.

Comment: What you're suggesting creates an extra copy if the actual argument was a temporary (say the result of a function that returned a std::string).

Comment: @pelletjl - No, if the value comes from a function that returns a `std::string` then the reference will bind to that temporary without copying it.

Comment: Creating a copy from a temporary results in an implicit move. So it is fine a "pass by value": it is moved implicitly in the parameter and then explicitly from the parameter to the member, with no copy at all.

  * If the starting value is not temporary, a copy is generated in the parameter that is them moved explicitly in the member (so one copy is done, unless an explicit move is pecifyed in the call)

  * With a pass by reference, a copy from the paramenter's referred object to the member is always done. No move are possible being the source referred as const  (and hence, not modifiable)

Comment: @Sean - only if your class members are references, which isn't what the OP states. In what you have, name is copied to m_name and surname to m_surname. These are the extra copy that std::move avoids.