# Move-semantics vs const reference

Tags: c++, string, reference, move-semantics

my class has string variables and I want to initialize them with values passed to the constructor.

My teacher thought us to pass strings as a const-reference:

```cpp
MyClass::MyClass(const std::string &title){
  this->title = title
}
```

However Clang-Tidy suggest using the move command:

```cpp
MyClass::MyClass(std::string title){
  this->title = std::move(title)
}
```

So I'm wondering what the correct way to do this in modern C++ is.

I already looked around, but nothing really answered my question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: In general, yes, second version is current standard. It may sometimes avoid a copy, while second always will perform a copy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Const reference VS move semantics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642357/const-reference-vs-move-semantics)

Comment: If C++ had COW for `std::string`, then there would be a good case for the first.

Comment: For a situation like this, where the parameter is a *data sink*, I'd use `MyClass::MyClass(std::string title_) : title{std::move(title_)} {}`.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Quibble: I'd call it "best practice" rather than "standard", also given the caveat in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None is optimal since they both default construct `title` first and then *copy assign* or *move assign* it. Use the member initializer list.

```
MyClass::MyClass(const std::string& title) : title(title) {}         // #1
// or
MyClass::MyClass(std::string title) : title(std::move(title)) {}     // #2
//or
MyClass::MyClass(const std::string& title) : title(title) {}         // #3
MyClass::MyClass(std::string&& title) : title(std::move(title)) {}   // #3
```

Let's look at them and see what happens in C++17:

---

#1 - A single converting constructor taking a `const&`.

```
MyClass::MyClass(const std::string& title) : title(title) {}
```

This will create 1 or 2 `std::string`s in one of these ways:

- The member is copy constructed.
- A `std::string` is constructed by a `std::string` converting constructor and then the member is copy constructed.

---

#2 - A single converting constructor taking a `std::string` by value.

```
MyClass(std::string title) : title(std::move(title)) {}
```

This will create 1 or 2 `std::string`s in one of these ways:

- The argument is constructed by [*return value optimization*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) from a temporary (`str1` + `str2`) and then the member is move constructed.
- The argument is copy constructed and then the member is move constructed.
- The argument is move constructed and then the member is move constructed.
- The argument is constructed by a `std::string` converting constructor and then the member is move constructed.

---

#3 - Combining two converting constructors.

```
MyClass(const std::string& title) : title(title) {}
MyClass(std::string&& title) : title(std::move(title)) {}
```

This will create 1 or 2 `std::string`s in one of these ways:

- The member is copy constructed.
- The member is move constructed.
- A `std::string` is constructed by a `std::string` converting constructor and then the member is move constructed.

---

So far, option `#3` seems to be the most efficient option. Let's check a few options more.

---

#4 - Like #3 but replacing the moving conversion constructor with a forwarding constructor.

```
MyClass(const std::string& title) : title(title) {}                       // A
template<typename... Args>
explicit MyClass(Args&&... args) : title(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}  // B
```

This will always create 1 `std::string` in one of these ways:

- The member is copy constructed via `A`.
- The member is move constructed via `B`.
- The member is constructed by a `std::string` (possibly converting) constructor via `B`.

---

#5 - A forwarding constructor only - removing the copying conversion constructor from #4.

```
template<typename... Args>
explicit MyClass(Args&&... args) : title(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}
```

This will always create 1 `std::string` like in #4, but all is done via the forwarding constructor.

- The member is copy constructed.
- The member is move constructed.
- The member is constructed by a `std::string` (possibly converting) constructor.

---

#6 - A single argument forwarding conversion constructor.

```
template<typename T>
explicit MyClass(T&& title) : title(std::forward<T>(title)) {}
```

This will always create 1 `std::string` like in #4 and #5 but will only take one argument and forward it to the `std::string` constructor.

- The member is copy constructed.
- The member is move constructed.
- The member is constructed by a `std::string` converting constructor.

---

Option `#6` can easily be used to do perfect forwarding if you want to take multiple arguments in the `MyClass` constructor. Let's say you have an `int` member and another `std::string` member:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
MyClass(int X, T&& title, U&& title2) :
    x(X),
    title(std::forward<T>(title)),
    title2(std::forward<U>(title2))
{}
```

Comment: Awesome. Follow-up question about a similar scenario:  Is it possible to modify #4 so that I can pass multiple strings? And what if I wanted to pass multiple strings and an integer?

Comment: @Finn I added option #6 for that - and I noticed that I forgot forwarding references in #5 so I rewrote that option now. :)

Comment: Hm. I tried #6 now and  CLion says everything is correct, but when I compile it, I get an error. It can't find the constructor. (Undefined reference). Do I need multiple constructors like in #4?

Comment: @Finn [example](https://godbolt.org/z/WMa73c) - You didn't try to put the implementation of the member function template in your `.cpp` file, did you? The member function template should be in the `.hpp` file.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I tried.. Putting everything in the header file worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Copying a reference creates a copy of the original variable (original and the new one are on different areas), moving a local variable casts to a rvalue your local variable (and again, original and the new one are on different areas).

From the compiler point of view, `move` may be (and is) faster:

```
#include <string>

void MyClass(std::string title){
  std::string title2 = std::move(title);
}
```

translates to:

```
MyClass(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >): # @MyClass(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)
        sub     rsp, 40
        mov     rax, rdi
        lea     rcx, [rsp + 24]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], rcx
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rdi]
        lea     rdx, [rax + 16]
        cmp     rdi, rdx
        je      .LBB0_1
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], rdi
        mov     rsi, qword ptr [rax + 16]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 24], rsi
        jmp     .LBB0_3
.LBB0_1:
        movups  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rdi]
        movups  xmmword ptr [rcx], xmm0
        mov     rdi, rcx
.LBB0_3:
        mov     rsi, qword ptr [rax + 8]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 16], rsi
        mov     qword ptr [rax], rdx
        mov     qword ptr [rax + 8], 0
        mov     byte ptr [rax + 16], 0
        cmp     rdi, rcx
        je      .LBB0_5
        call    operator delete(void*)
.LBB0_5:
        add     rsp, 40
        ret
```

However,

```
void MyClass(std::string& title){
  std::string title = title;
}
```

generates a bigger code (similar for GCC):

```
MyClass(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&): # @MyClass(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)
        push    r15
        push    r14
        push    rbx
        sub     rsp, 48
        lea     r15, [rsp + 32]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 16], r15
        mov     r14, qword ptr [rdi]
        mov     rbx, qword ptr [rdi + 8]
        test    r14, r14
        jne     .LBB0_2
        test    rbx, rbx
        jne     .LBB0_11
.LBB0_2:
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 8], rbx
        mov     rax, r15
        cmp     rbx, 16
        jb      .LBB0_4
        lea     rdi, [rsp + 16]
        lea     rsi, [rsp + 8]
        xor     edx, edx
        call    std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_M_create(unsigned long&, unsigned long)
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 16], rax
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rsp + 8]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 32], rcx
.LBB0_4:
        test    rbx, rbx
        je      .LBB0_8
        cmp     rbx, 1
        jne     .LBB0_7
        mov     cl, byte ptr [r14]
        mov     byte ptr [rax], cl
        jmp     .LBB0_8
.LBB0_7:
        mov     rdi, rax
        mov     rsi, r14
        mov     rdx, rbx
        call    memcpy
.LBB0_8:
        mov     rax, qword ptr [rsp + 8]
        mov     qword ptr [rsp + 24], rax
        mov     rcx, qword ptr [rsp + 16]
        mov     byte ptr [rcx + rax], 0
        mov     rdi, qword ptr [rsp + 16]
        cmp     rdi, r15
        je      .LBB0_10
        call    operator delete(void*)
.LBB0_10:
        add     rsp, 48
        pop     rbx
        pop     r14
        pop     r15
        ret
.LBB0_11:
        mov     edi, offset .L.str
        call    std::__throw_logic_error(char const*)
.L.str:
        .asciz  "basic_string::_M_construct null not valid"
```

So yes, `std::move` is better (under these circumstances).

Answer (score 0):

It' ok use a const reference, then use member initializer lists:

```
MyClass(const std::string &title) : m_title{title}
```

Where m_title is your member string in the class.

You can find useful help here: [Constructor member initializer lists](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/8-5a-constructor-member-initializer-lists/)

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 cases: **lvalue** or **rvalue** of `std::string`.

in `std::string const&` version, **lvalue** case is efficient enough, **passed by reference and then copied**. but a **rvalue** will be **copied** rather than **moved**, which is in much lower efficiency.

in `std::string` version, **lvalue** is **copied when passed**, and then **moved** to the member. **rvalue** will be **moved twice** in this case. but generally it's **cheap**, the move constructor.

besides, in `std::string&&` version, it can not receive a **lvalue**, but **rvalue** is **passed by reference and then moved**, better than moved twice.

so obviously, it's the best practice with both `const&` and `&&`, as what STL always does. but if move constructor is cheap enough, just passing by value and moving is also acceptable.