# Why pass a string by reference and make it a constant?

Tags: c++

Just a general question say the signature of a function is:

```
void f( const string & s )...
```

Why is it necessary to pass this by reference if you are not actually changing the string (since it is constant)?

Comment: To avoid making an unnecessary and wasteful copy.

Answer (score 6):

There are two alternatives to passing by reference - passing by pointer, and passing by value.

Passing by pointer is similar to passing by reference: the same argument of "why pass a pointer if you do not want to modify it" could be made for it.

Passing by value requires making a copy. Copying a string is usually more expensive, because dynamic memory needs to be allocated and de-allocated under the cover. That is why it is often a better idea to pass a `const` reference / pointer than passing a copy that you are not planning to change.

Comment: Since passing by reference allows the function to modify the caller's copy - it should be const ref unless modify behaviour is specifically required

Answer (score 3):

When you pass a variable by value, it makes a copy. Passing by reference avoids that copy. You want to mark it `const` for the same reason: Since you're not making a copy, you don't want to accidentally mess with the original. I think this could also potentially allow for compiler optimizations.

The reason you don't usually see this for `int`, `char`, `float`, and other primitive types is that they're relatively cheap to copy, and in some cases, passing by reference is more expensive (for example, passing a `char` by reference could involve passing 64-bits of data (the pointer) instead of 8-bits. Passing by reference also adds some indirection, which isn't a big deal with a big type like a string, but is wasteful for something like an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

It is not "necessary," but the common answer is "for performance reasons, to prevent copying," however that is a naive answer and the truth is a bit more complex.

In your example, assuming `s` really is immutable and something you don't "own or can't change," then the `const` decorator is appropriate for `s`. If the reference of `s` wasn't taken, then that would guarantee a copied (excluding compiler optimizations).

If `f()` is not going to use the copy of `s` after `f()` returns, then the effort of copying `s` was wasted. So, passing by reference prevents the copying and `f()` retains the ability to inspect the string `s`. Great. And again, that's the naive answer and pre-C++11, would be the mostly correct answer.

There are more scenarios worth considering in order to answer "is it necessary?" but I'll focus on just one:

> If the caller of `f()` doesn't need the string `s` after invoking
>   `f()`, but `f()` needs to retain a copy of the data.

Suppose the code is:

```
void f(const std::string& arg1);   // f()'s signature
void g(const std::string& arg1) {
   std::string s(arg1);
   s.append(" mutate s");
   f(s);
}
```

In this case, you would have constructed the string `s`, passed it by `const` reference to `f()`, and everything is fine from a performance perspective if you assume `f()` is opaque and there are no further optimizations available.

Now, suppose `f()` needs a copy of the data in `s`, then what? Well, `f()` will call a copy constructor and copy `s` in to a local variable:

```
 // Hypothetical f()
 void f(const std::string& s) {
   this->someString_ = s;
 }
```

In this case, by the time the data is stored in `someString_`, the normal constructor will have been called in `g()`, and the copy ctor will have been called in `f()`, however the work done in `g()` will have been wasted. To improve performance, there are two things that can be done, pass by value and/or use move constructors.

```
// Explicitly move arg1 in to someString_
void f(std::string&& arg1) {
  this->somestring_ = std::move(arg1);
}

void g(const std::string& arg1) {
   std::string s(arg1);
   s.append(" mutate s");
   f(s);
}
```

Which is explicitly doing what the compiler will automatically do starting with `C++11`, which means the more correct version is to pass by value and let the compiler do the right thing:

```
void f(std::string arg1) {
  this->somestring_ = arg1; // Implicit move, let the compiler do the right thing
}

void g(const std::string& arg1) {
   std::string s(arg1);
   s.append(" mutate s");
   f(s);
}
```

And in this case, the string is constructed in `g()` and no additional work was done anywhere. So in this case, the answer to,

> Why is it necessary to pass this by reference if you are not actually
>   changing the string (since it is constant)?

The string wasn't changed, but it was copied, and therefore **const reference was not necessary**.

It's an exercise for the reader to list the optimizations the compiler can take when `s` is or isn't mutated after the call to `f()`.

I can't recommend enough that people look in to David Abrams's post, '[Want Speed? Pass by value](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:GLdM1_YvqhEJ:cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/%20&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us)' or [Is it better in C++ to pass by value or pass by constant reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270408/is-it-better-in-c-to-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-constant-reference) and post [How to pass objects to functions in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2139254/736571).

Comment: It is necessary to bind a rvalue.

Answer (score 0):

in other words, you would get the speed of passing by reference ( not making extra copies ).
and the integrity of passing by value ( the original variable value is not changed)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't 'necessary', but it's a very good idea, for several reasons:

1. Efficiency. Not creating or destroying new strings is more efficient than creating and destroying them, especially as strings are arbitrary in length and therefore require dynamically allocated memory.
2. A `string` can be constructed from a string literal. If you specify `const` you allow the compiler to construct a temporary `string` from a literal so that the caller can just provide the literal rather than the `string` object. If you don't specify `const` the compiler can't do that, so the caller can't do that either.

Comment: Assuming a non-`const` literal, it's not always guaranteed to be faster due to [Copy Elision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision). In `C++11`, if you overuse `const`, you are preventing the use of [move semantics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Rvalue_references_and_move_constructors).