# How are templates work so that the classes are properly generated by the compiler to work with both pointer types and non pointer types?

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, constants

Given

```cpp
int i = 42;
int* p = &i;
```

we cannot do

```cpp
const int * & d = p;
```

In my current understanding, this is because `const int * & d` can be read as "`d` is a reference of a pointer to an `int` that is a `const`" and `p` is "a pointer to an `int`", which means the RHS needs to be turned into a temporary being "a pointer to an `int` that is a `const`" and that cannot be binded directly with a reference (as on the LHS). We would need to have, say, `const int* const& d = p;`. *Possible references*: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3247339/16500459), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37356314/16500459).

That said, consider the following toy code:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class X
{
public:
    void fun(const T& d) {  }
};
```

At first, I thought if I do

```cpp
X<int*> x;
x.fun(p);
```

The method generated by the compiler would be `void fun(const int*& d)`, and I would get an error due to the above reason.

However, there is no error and it works "as expected" (by that I mean, we always have `d` itself as the `const` no matter `T` is replaced by pointer types or by non-pointer types).

My current guess is that, for the above scenario, the method generated by the compiler is something like `void fun(int* const& d)`.

May I ask if my guess is correct? How are templates work so that the classes generated by the compiler work with pointers "as expected"?

Comment: It is not limited to templates, but works the same for typedefs and a using-alias. The `const` is applied to all of T, not to one of its "components".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your guess is correct.

For `const T`, `const` is qualified on type `T` directly. Given `T` is `int*` (non-`const` pointer to non-`const` `int`), `const T` results in `const` pointer, i.e. `int* const` (`const` pointer to non-`const` `int`) but not `const int*` (non-`const` pointer to `const` `int`).

Comment: That's why I prefer tail CV qualifications over lead CV qualifications. I mean `T const` looks more consistent to me than `const T`. With tail CV qualifications, the OP wouldn't missinterpret the expression.