# Does using const CString& instead of CString alone as function parameter have any performance benefit?

Tags: c++, c++11, constants

I have a function that takes a `CString` as one of the parameters and I was looking through the code base and many places have `const CString&` instead as a argument.

So I want to know if there is a performance or behavior difference between using `CString` vs `const CString&`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it better in C++ to pass by value or pass by constant reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270408/is-it-better-in-c-to-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-constant-reference)

Comment: Are we talking about MFC/ATL `CString`?

Answer (score 1):

Passing by value for a C++ non-trivial class involves invoking the copy constructor, so the decision, performance-wise, depends from what it does.

If we are talking about MFC/ATL `CString`, its copy constructor doesn't perform a deep copy like `std::string` (which may indeed be quite costly to copy, as, in the general case, it requires a new allocation and the copy of the full content), as it implements "copy on write" optimization - copies of a given `CString` actually share the backing buffer until one of them tries to modify it, thus triggering the actual copy. For this reason, copies are relatively cheap, but they still involve some atomic integer fiddling, which may be not completely free on modern processors.

So: most probably a `const` reference is going to be slightly faster to pass (even though access to actual data inside the function is going to suffer slightly due to an extra indirection step), but that's not anything I'd really worry about unless profiling does show it to be a bottleneck.

Answer (score -1):

Usually no. A good compiler & optimizer should produce the same assembly.

This is because references are implemented as pointers in all of the major compilers and passing a trivial data type such as a `char*` via value or pointer makes no difference because at assembly level the passing of the argument to the function is both the same, `sizeof(char*) == sizeof(char**)`.

Comment: Well it depends from the semantic of `CString`... If it's COW then your reasoning is right, if instead it's like `std::string` the copy constructor is way more heavyweight than just copying a pointer...

Comment: @MatteoItalia Definitely right, I instantly assumed OP meant `char*` though.

Comment: This answer is terrible. It doesn't address the question or even the title of the question.

Comment: @HerrJoebob Yes it does. And yes it does. But hey what do I know :)