# How to iterate over a vector within a struct?

Tags: c++, loops, struct, iterator, stdvector

I am creating a digital vending machine of sorts for school and have run into an issue. I created a struct of `Items` for vending. I then created a struct called `Machine` that contains a `vector<Items>`. I wanted to create a for loop that iterates over the `vector<Item>` and displays the items but I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\Nate\Desktop>g++ structversion.cpp -o structversion.exe -std=c++11
structversion.cpp: In function 'int test(Machine)':
structversion.cpp:29:20: error: 'begin' was not declared in this scope
   for (Item item : machine) {
                    ^
structversion.cpp:29:20: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/string:51:0,
                 from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from structversion.cpp:1:
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/range_access.h:87:5: note:   'std::begin'
     begin(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])
     ^
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/range_access.h:87:5: note:   'std::begin'
structversion.cpp:29:20: error: 'end' was not declared in this scope
   for (Item item : machine) {
                    ^
structversion.cpp:29:20: note: suggested alternatives:
In file included from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/string:51:0,
                 from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ios:42,
                 from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/ostream:38,
                 from C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/iostream:39,
                 from structversion.cpp:1:
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/range_access.h:97:5: note:   'std::end'
     end(_Tp (&__arr)[_Nm])
     ^
C:/TDM-GCC-64/lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/5.1.0/include/c++/bits/range_access.h:97:5: note:   'std::end'
```

I apologize if this is a redundant or dumb question. Also here is the code at issue:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Item 
{
    string name;
    double price;
    unsigned int quantity;
    unsigned int amountInCart;
    bool addedToCart;
};

struct Machine { vector<Item> menu; };

void initItem(Item& i, string name, double price, unsigned int quantity,
    unsigned int amountInCart, bool addedToCart) 
{
    i.name = name;
    i.price = price;
    i.quantity = quantity;
    i.amountInCart = amountInCart;
    i.addedToCart = addedToCart;
}

test(Machine machine)
{
    for (Item i : machine) {
        cout << "item = " << i.name;
    }
}

main()
{
    Item cake;
    Item fruit;
    Item chips;
    Item soda;
    Item juice;

    initItem(cake, "Cake", 3.00, 5, 0, false);
    initItem(fruit, "Fruit", 4.20, 15, 0, false);
    initItem(chips, "Chips", 1.00, 6, 0, false);
    initItem(soda, "Soda", 1.50, 7, 0, false);
    initItem(juice, "Juice", 1.90, 10, 0, false);

    Machine machine;
    machine.menu.push_back(cake);
    machine.menu.push_back(fruit);
    machine.menu.push_back(chips);
    machine.menu.push_back(soda);
    machine.menu.push_back(juice);

    test(machine);
    return 0;
}
```

The function `test` is where I am trying to iterate over the vector menu within the `Machine` struct.

I am fairly new so if anyone has time and could ELI5 what I am doing wrong that would be amazing.

Comment: Hope that is a copy-paste typo: your `test` and `main` missed the returns.

Comment: oh yes it was! This was just a snippet I took of the broken code from my main project which is bigger. Just wanted to only include the relevant code. Once again thanks for the assist.

Comment: You should learn what a constructor is, please do not use obscure init functions! Also you can use aggregate initialization in your case here.

Answer (score 5):

In order to use the [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) in your user-defined types, you need to define `begin()` and `end()` iterators. That means, `Machine` needs to have the following member functions which return the iterator of the member container. **([See live online](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1gKTZ4YhrZyySPdA))**

```
struct Machine
{
    vector<Item> menu;
    auto begin() { return menu.begin(); } // auto return requires C++14
    auto end()   { return menu.end();   }

    // or in C++11, you provide the correct return type
    // decltype(menu.begin()) begin() { return menu.begin(); }
    // decltype(menu.end())   end()   { return menu.end();   }
};
```

---

Otherwise, you need to provide the iterative object directly to the loop. That means, in your case, in order to work with a minimal change:

```
void test(Machine const& machine) // pass by `const-ref` as the machine is read-only inside the function
{
    for (const Item& i : machine.menu) { // const& : same reason as above ^^
    //                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^ --> std::vector has iterators: begin(), end() 
        cout << "item = " << i.name;
    }
}
```

---

Some other notes:

- The `initItem` function is not the way you do in normally in C++ (or any other object-oriented programming languages). That is the job of a [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list). In order to change the value of the member(s) in an object, the setter (member) function will be used. A good starting would be:

  ```cpp
  class Item
  {
  private:
      std::string name;
      double price;
      unsigned int quantity;
      unsigned int amountInCart;
      bool addedToCart;

  public:
      // constructor
      Item(std::string name, double price, unsigned int quantity,
          unsigned int amountInCart, bool addedToCart)
          : name{ name } // or name{ std::move(name) } when you learn about the move-semantics
          , price{ price}
          , quantity{ quantity }
          , amountInCart{ amountInCart }
          , addedToCart{ addedToCart }
      {}
      // ... getter and setter functions
  };
  ```

  You create an object now like:

  ```cpp
  Item cake{ "Cake", 3.00, 5, 0, false };
  ```
- Please do not practice with `using namespace std;`. See here for more: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)
- I have passed the `Machine` object to the function `test`(also in range based loop, `Item` objects) passed by `const` qualified referance. Whenver, the data is non-modifiable under the any scopes, you should pass the parameters like that, so that unwanted copying can be avoided(*creadits @Klaus*): . For further readings: [Is it better in C++ to pass by value or pass by constant reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270408/is-it-better-in-c-to-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-constant-reference)

Comment: Oh wow I see. That is very simple. Thank you very much for the quick response and your help!

Comment: You should auto& instead of auto please! If not, you take a copy of every string you iterate over!

Comment: @Klaus Oh ja.. for sure. Added in the answer. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: Maybe you can add some hint *why* you use ref. You pointed out the "read only" which did not describe the "need" for ref here. I only mention this as the original code from OP is far away from c++ so it is maybe an idea to help around all that important c++ features here and make your answer more helpful. BTW: There is no need for a constructor as you can use aggregate initialization and an = default will also be enough. OK, it grows and grows :-)

Comment: @Klaus Adding more helpful notes: of course good, but I wanted to explain the problem what OP really had in the code. The code improvements should have been always unrelated comments, not in the answer, unless it demands. I have updated anyway including a further reading.